# How to test a Django on_commit hook without clearing the database?

Tags: python, django, testing, transactions

The [on_commit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.on_commit) function has been added to Django 1.9 to be able to trigger an action (e.g. a Celery task) after the current transaction has committed.

They mention later [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/#use-in-tests) that one should use `TransactionTestCase` to test features that rely on that function. However, unlike `TestCase` (which uses transactions and rolls them back), `TransactionTestCase` empties the whole database after each test.

Unfortunately, I have data migrations that preload some useful data inside the database, which means that subsequent tests do not work anymore after the first test clears the database.

I ended up resorting to a dirty trick by mocking `on_commit` :

```
with mock.patch.object(django.db.transaction, 'on_commit', lambda t: t()):
    test_something()
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Actually your workaround is not that bad. And I don't want to use `TransactionTestCase` because it's slow for my usecase (large `setUp`s and lots of fixtures.)

Comment: I really like this workaround - doesn't work in some cases for some reason I haven't explored yet but it's definitely better than mine (an exec_on_commit() function that executes whatever was supposed to be executed on commit).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting with version 3.2 Django has a build-in way to test the on_comit hook.
Example:

```
from django.core import mail
from django.test import TestCase


class ContactTests(TestCase):
    def test_post(self):
        with self.captureOnCommitCallbacks(execute=True) as callbacks:
            response = self.client.post(
                '/contact/',
                {'message': 'I like your site'},
            )

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(len(callbacks), 1)
        self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1)
        self.assertEqual(mail.outbox[0].subject, 'Contact Form')
        self.assertEqual(mail.outbox[0].body, 'I like your site')
```

Here is the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.captureOnCommitCallbacks

Comment: Nice, thank you! I'll change the accepted answer since this is much more recent than the original one ;)

Answer (score 10):

Just keep using TestCase and fake commit forcing executing of posponed actions in *run_and_clear_commit_hooks*.
Check this article:

https://medium.com/gitux/speed-up-django-transaction-hooks-tests-6de4a558ef96

Comment: This is an interesting hack, hence the upvote, but I'd be wary of using internal Django methods lest you end up with issues when upgrading...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Django 2.2.1:
`File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 438, in validate_no_broken_transaction`
`"An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't "`
`django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.`

Answer (score 1):

Adam Johnson wrote this, and I think the code referenced here does the trick:

https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/05/20/the-fast-way-to-test-django-transaction-on-commit-callbacks/

```
@contextmanager
    def captureOnCommitCallbacks(cls, *, using=DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS, execute=False):
        """Context manager to capture transaction.on_commit() callbacks."""
        callbacks = []
        start_count = len(connections[using].run_on_commit)
        try:
            yield callbacks
        finally:
            run_on_commit = connections[using].run_on_commit[start_count:]
            callbacks[:] = [func for sids, func in run_on_commit]
            if execute:
                for callback in callbacks:
                    callback()
```

usage:

```
class ContactTests(TestCase):
            def test_post(self):
                with self.captureOnCommitCallbacks(execute=True) as callbacks:
                    response = self.client.post(
                        '/contact/',
                        {'message': 'I like your site'},
                    )

                self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
                self.assertEqual(len(callbacks), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two possibilities in mind:

1. as [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/advanced/#advanced-features-of-transactiontestcase) section says `post_migrate` emitted after flush, so you can perform preloading some useful data
2. You can subclass `TransactionTestCase` and implement your `_fixture_teardown` (you can see that flush is called there in the very end of method).

I'd probably stick with first one if your migration isn't too expensive and with second one if it is.

Comment: Using the `post_migrate` signal is a good idea. I'll see if I can convert our data migrations to this because it sounds overall much cleaner!